# How do I un-apply a slide master to a PowerPoint slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PPT presentation (Mac PowerPoint 15.18 -- latest) that, for whatever reason, has more than one master assigned to *some of* the slides.  This is considerably screwing things up for me.  I've tried to delete the unwanted master in the Slide Master view, but it won't let me do it, presumably since it's assigned to one or more slides.  So: How do I remove the assignment of that master to this slide (which, I guess, is all I really want to do)?  Thanks

Comment: Since in theory you can't have a slide with more than one master applied, I'm inclined to confusion here.  How have you determined that more than one master rules the slide?  A couple of screenshots would do wonders here.  Or do you mean that more than one slide is assigned to a single master or layout? In that case, apply a different layout to each of the slides concerned.  Once no more slides depend on the layout, you'll be able to delete it.

Comment: Aha, my bad -- I was confusing masters and layouts.  Duh.  Everything is now fine, but thanks for the advice in any case!